# How do I fix "Error: No pubspec.yaml file found." in flutter w/ Android studio?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've been looking and googling for a while and couldn't find a fitting answer, I've tried different commands through the terminal, as was suggested in some forums but nothing really helped.
I have this issue for some reason only with a specific project, other flutter projects that I have are running with no issues at all

For Example, I've tried to run this in the terminal and this is what I got:

```
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project
```

Any help, suggestions, and recommendations would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you make sure that your terminal is at the project directory?

Comment: did you tried running `flutter clean` and then `flutter create .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decided to reinstall android studio and make sure that everything is correct with the PATH of the SDK, and reinstalled the SDK tools.
pretty much worked for some reason

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the fact that you are running the `flutter run` command from a different directory. Usually, when you try this command, you are in the parent directory instead of the root directory.

Try running the `flutter run` command from the project directory using the `cd YOUR_ROOT_DIRECTORY` command you can enter to that directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really do appreciate it. but I'm having issues to get to the root directory, I've been trying to check if everything is well with terminal's settings path and such and also the path in the directory looks already like the root's path. tbh I'm quite confused

Comment: please share its pic. 
Also, You can right-click in your project and select `show in explorer`. now just copy this directory + `/projectName` and go inside it using `cd` command